# Magento Shop by Brands

Tags: magento

I am trying to add shop by brands in navigation.Here is my code

```
<?php
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attributeInfo=Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code','shoe_type')->load(false);
$attribute=$attributeInfo->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
$shoes=$attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
$url='catalogsearch/result/?q=';
foreach($shoes as $shoe):
    $val=$shoe['label'];
?>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getURL().$url.$val?>"><?php echo $shoe['label']?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Obviously,output takes me to search results page which displays as Search Results for brand http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7303/searchd.jpg. But i want result page without the text `search results for`.

Is their any other way to display shop by brands in navigation?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why ain't you using layered navigation?

Comment: @Dick Laurent:I want to display brands in top navigation.

Comment: Do as you did in your question but instead of linking to search results page link to layered navigation. http://demo.magentocommerce.com/bed-and-bath?color=59

Comment: @Dick Laurent:Could you give clue for layered navigation $url

Comment: It depends on your category structure. Personally I prefer another approach making brands not on attributes but categories (e.g. make two root categories "Categories" and "Brands". one will hold categories as sub-categories and another brands).

Comment: The layered navigation will only work within one category.

Comment: @Dick Laurent:Sounds good to me.Thank you!

Comment: Cool, will publish it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I prefer another approach making brands not on attributes but categories (e.g. make two root categories "Categories" and "Brands". one will hold categories as sub-categories and another brands).