# Magento brands by categories: show brand link

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm setting up a webshop for a client in Magento.
He works a lot with very specific brands, so I wanted to make specific brands pages (for SEO purposes).

I followed the suggestion mentioned here: [Mangento Shop By Brand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292448/magento-shop-by-brands) to make categories out of brands.
It all works great, I can access my pages like `example.com/brands/brandname`.

But now, when in a products view, I want to link to that brand page.
How can I get a list of the categories for that product, or even the specific subcategory.
I thought about filtering categories by their parent_id (my brands page itself). But haven't got a clue how to go about doing it.
I found som info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521021/magento-list-products-categories) but doesn't seem to work for my Magento (1.4.1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to do the work: [Aitoc commercial module to shop by brand](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_shop_by_brands.html#demo)

Or I tried this code with Magento 1.4.1 which display the list/url of category/ies that the product belongs to, inspired of the link you provided and it works, put it in a block to allow the template to display the url:

```
public function getProductUrl($productId){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(productId);
    $currentCatIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if ($currentCatIds) {
        $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
            ->addIsActiveFilter();
        foreach ($categoryCollection->getItems() as $item) {
            /*echo $item->getName();
            echo $item->getUrl();
            echo '<br>';*/
            if($item->getUrl()) return $item->getUrl();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the following line: `->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 71)` to filter out only categories under "brands" (which is 71 for me). Thanks for the advice!